# Upgrade Ubuntu without losing Grub dual-boot settings?

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, windows

I would like to over-write the partition with my Ubuntu, without losing all my dual-boot configurations. My dual boot is (I think) configured using grub.

Can I install a new version of Ubuntu without over-writing my Grub settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Hard Drive, in the first few sectors, there is space reserved specificity for the Boot Loader. In your case, it is Grub. Should you overwrite Ubuntu with a new version, the installer will overwrite all your Grub settings, but then it will create a new Grub, and then indexing the Windows Partitions.

In short, all you dual boot settings will be overwritten, but dual-boot will work again, as when grub is reinstalled, it will see Windows.

Hope this answers it.

Comment: Ok, I am using the USB boot loader and it says "This computer currently has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it". I am ok selecting "Erase Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and reinstall" ? This will keep my grub settings?

Comment: What will happen is, it will Delete Ubuntu, Reinstall it, and at the end of the install, it will reinstall grub, thus, you will be able to boot into windows again.

Comment: If you are worried about losing windows, you can click `something else` and manually delete Ubuntu, and then set Ubuntu to install in that place. However, the Reinstall option should work.